# Am I using DSolve correctly?

Tags: differential-equations, homework

I'm new to Mathematica but I think I solved the problem shown below. I want to know if I solved it right. Your response will be much appreciated.

[image: Question]

```
DSolve[y''[t] == 3 y[t] + 3 Sin[t] && y[0] == 0 && y'[0] == 1, y[t],t]
```

I copied the answer from the `DSolve like` this:

```
z = 1/24 E^(-Sqrt[3] t) (-7 Sqrt[3] + 7 Sqrt[3] E^(2 Sqrt[3] t) - 
 18 E^(Sqrt[3] t) Sin[t]);
```

[image: copied answer]

Finally, I plotted the plot function:

```
Plot[z, {t, 0, 20}, PlotStyle -> Red]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks OK to me, but here is a way to go about it that makes checking the result easier.

```
yF = DSolve[y''[t] == 3 y[t] + 3 Sin[t] && y[0] == 0 && y'[0] == 1, y, t][[1, 1, 2]];
FullSimplify[yF''[t] == 3 yF[t] + 3 Sin[t] && yF[0] == 0 && yF'[0] == 1]
```

> `True`